# We need a multimodal tag

Tags: discussion

We need a tag "multimodal" that would cover the use of bicycles in mixed-use commuting and travel:

1. Bus and bike (see recent questions)
2. Trains and bikes
3. Airplanes and bikes
4. Ferries and bikes

These don't fit that well under the generic "transportation" tag. The other possible tag "commuting" is also similarly too generic.

Comment: I like the idea, but I am not keen on the tag name. See my answer for some possible alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have thought the commuter or commuting tag would cover this need?

EDIT Evidently they are different, overlapping but not identical.

Vote: Add the tag and see what happens.

Comment: Not all commuters are multimodal and not all multi-modal users are commuters. :-(

Comment: @RoboKaren  Fair call.

Answer (score 1):

I think a new tag would be appropriate, although I am not too keen on the term "multimodal" as it may be too abstract and academic for the lay audience.  And it is not clear what modes are being referred too (e.g., road and gravel path could be considered mixed modes - at least by me).

I would suggest "mixed-mode" or "mixed-mode transportation" as a possible alternative, with the second being the most self-explanatory.